# Custom View Width

Tags: java, android, view

I've created a class for a custom view, and I overrode the onMeasure method like I show next.
But when i call the getter for width and height, their always returns 0. Why does that happen?

```java
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);
   }
```

Comment: Are you setting the width and height??

Comment: where do you call the getWidth || Height..?!

Comment: You must wait for your layout to actually layout itself. You are probably calling getWidth / getHeight in onCreate method. You need to wait for the app to actually put elements on the screen. Try `Handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay)` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The getWidth() and getHeight() values will only be available after the first full layout pass (OnMeasure -> OnLayout) so if you really need to access those values in between use getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight()